# Customize Python package - django-paypal

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, paypal, django-paypal

I'm working on a project in which I need to make some changes in [django-paypal](https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal) package. I have cloned the package's GitHub repo and make a very simple change **(Just change a form submit type=image source)** and then install it via `python setup.py install` but now I couldn't find any path to import this package.

For example when I install it by using `pip install django-paypal` i was able to import it like `from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm` but after installing it via `python setup.py install` from my local changed source then it couldn't find any `paypal` package.

How can i fix this issue?

Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you not configure this with a setting? https://django-paypal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/settings.html#PAYPAL_BUY_BUTTON_IMAGE

Comment: Hi @Blender, that was just an example I need to make various changes like I also need to add `target="_blank"` to `PaypalPaymentsForm` .

Comment: I would just subclass `PaypalPaymentsForm` and override the `render()` method to return the modified HTML. Unless you're making tons of  extensive modifications to core functionality, you usually don't want to maintain your own copy of a package. This will make upgrading difficult.

Comment: it sounds good, can you guide me a little bit how I can override the render method? please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually want to avoid modifying the source code of modules directly. This will make upgrading difficult and will require you to somehow bundle those modified packages along with your own code, which makes distributing your code difficult.

Instead of changing the string returned by `PayPalPaymentsForm.render`, just subclass it and modify the `render` method to return the HTML you want:

**`your_app/forms.py`**

```
from django.utils.html import format_html
from paypal.standard.forms import PayPalPaymentsForm

class CustomPayPalPaymentsForm(PayPalPaymentsForm):
    def render(self):
        return format_html(u"""<form action="{0}" method="post">
    {1}
    <input type="image" src="{2}" border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy it Now" />
</form>""", self.get_endpoint(), self.as_p(), self.get_image())
```

Then you just import it:

```
from your_app.forms import CustomPayPalPaymentsForm
```

Comment: Hi @Blender, can you take a look at this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/q/49197631/7644562 please!

Comment: @AbdulRehman: It'd be easier to use email, I think. PayPal's IPN can have delays and tying that to a real-time application on the internet may not work well.

Comment: Hi @Blender, did you mean that I should send pdf file via the email to the user after successful payment?

Comment: @AbdulRehman: Yes. If you can't guarantee an immediate response from PayPal, email seems like the easiest compromise.

Comment: How can I achieve that? I need to generate a pdf from a Django template. Can you help me regarding this? please!

Comment: @AbdulRehman: Sorry, I never worked with PDF generation so I can't be of much help there. I'm sure there are many Python modules to do this.